# android - send parameters while uploading file

Tags: java, android, upload, httpconnection

I've got this piece of code http://pastebin.com/VrMNuxcv
which successfully uploads a file onto the server from my android.

I'd like to , however to be able to send a couple of string parameters together with it.

Could you please tell me, if possible,  where exactly I need to do this in that piece of code and how?

Thanks
Andreas

Comment: How do we get the parameter on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're in control of how the server processes the upload, i.e., you wrote the server code too???

If so, I simply use custom/private request properties (i.e., prefixed x-) for some client/server code I've written. Example...

```
conn.setRequestProperty("x-myapp-param1", "Parameter 1 text");
```

Any use to you?

Comment: I will try it and get back to you!

Comment: How do I get it on the server side? The tradiational way? i.e request.getParameter(...) ?

Comment: @kkudi: I guess it depends on which language your server code is written in. Mine is a simple HTTPListener (C#.NET) on a PC which allows me to get all header fields using Request.Headers.AllKeys. I run through them checking for "x-myapp-param1" (for example) then get the associated value.

Comment: works great! I thought the x- had to be ommitted on the server side! does it have to have the x at the front when sent from the client? Thank you so much ;-)

Comment: @kuddi: Glad to have helped. The HTTP specification allows for 'non-standard headers', i.e., private/custom data which is relevant only between clients/servers that know what the field keys/values mean. The convention is to prefix the key (at the client end) with "X-" to show that it is not part of the HTTP specification. Standard server implementations will simply ignore these but in your case (and mine) they are useful to allow our servers to look for our custom data by checking for anything prefixed "X-". I use "X-myapp-" just to add extra confirmation the data is from my client.

Comment: i can't get it, please can you elaborate it using any example  ?